# TypeORM return data from the month of a date

Tags: javascript, database, date, typeorm

I have an employee table and in it there is a date column. I'm trying to return all employees who have the same month informed of the entry date.
With the entry 2010-09-01 I want you to return all the employees you have in the column 2010-09-01 to 2010-09-30

```
async rangeDate(dateInput: string) {
  return await this.employeeRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('employee')      
    .where('employee.date = :dateInput')
    .setParameters({ dateInput })
    .getMany();
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using? What is the column type of `date`?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL and the date column is the same date type (no timestamps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT` function of PostgreSQL. See the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). Using this, the query can be written in the following way, after getting the month from the `dateInput`:

```
async rangeDate(dateInput: string) {
  const month = (new Date(dateInput)).getMonth() + 1;
  return await this.employeeRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('employee')      
    .where('EXTRACT(month, employee.date) = :month', { month: month })
    .getMany();
}
```

Comment: The entry will not always be on the first day of the month `2010-09-01`. For any selected day e.g. 2010-09-10 or 2010-09-29 I want it to return data for that month only. The return will be from the beginning of the month 2010-09-01 until 2010-09-30

Comment: @SteveSTS Please check now. I've removed the assumption.

Comment: sorry, Sorry it's not PostgreSQL it's MySQL. The EXTRACT would then look like this: `.where('EXTRACT(month FROM employee.date) = :month', { month: month })`?